# MySQL Query to get the first user that sums X sales

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for help with a query.

I have a users table and a sales table. Sales are stored with their date, amount and quantity.

I need to get the first user that reaches an X sum of amount or Y sum of sales.

So I would need to take the sale date in account in order to know which user gets it first.

Can anyone give me a hand with this query or should I use another approach?

I'm currenlty using MySQL 8.0.32.

Here are some sample tables and an example of what is needed.

Users

| id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 |
| 2 | user2 |

Sales

| id | amount | quantity | date | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 2 | 2023-01-05 | 1 |
| 2 | 1500 | 3 | 2023-01-05 | 2 |
| 3 | 500 | 1 | 2023-01-07 | 1 |
| 4 | 1500 | 3 | 2023-01-10 | 1 |
| 5 | 500 | 1 | 2023-01-12 | 1 |
| 6 | 2500 | 5 | 2023-01-12 | 2 |
| 7 | 1000 | 2 | 2023-01-15 | 1 |

In this case, lets assume that the goal is the first user to sum >=4000. So user2 would be the winner as it reaches to 4000 before user1 even when at the end user1 sums 4500.

I would expect to get the lists of users untill the date that the first user get to the goal ie:

| user_id | sum_amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4000 | 2023-01-12 |
| 1 | 3500 | 2023-01-12 |

That would be super, but I could handle getting the first user got to the goal.

Thanks.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. A [mcve], you know.

Comment: Also be specific about which version of MySQL you are using. Run `SELECT VERSION();` and report the result. The best answer may depends on features that are only supported the latest version.

Comment: Thanks. I've just updated the question with your advices.

Answer (score 3):

For MySql 8.0+ you can use `SUM()` window function to calculate the running total an sort the rows first by the rows that are equal or greater than 4000 and then the `date`:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM sales
ORDER BY SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) >= 4000 DESC, 
         date
LIMIT 1;
```

For previous versions of MySql use a correlated subquery that emulates the functionality of `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT s1.user_id
FROM sales s1
ORDER BY (SELECT SUM(s2.amount) 
          FROM sales s2 
          WHERE s2.user_id = s1.user_id AND s2.date <= s1.date
         ) >= 4000 DESC, 
         s1.date
LIMIT 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CGmgr1ku).